# Prove $f([a]_n) = \cos(2a\pi/n) +i\sin(2a\pi/n)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Define a function $f\colon \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mu_n$ by
>   $$f([a]_n) = \cos(2a\pi/n) +i\sin(2a\pi/n)$$
>   Prove that $f$ is an isomorphism.

I know by proving it is a bijection and $f(a*_1b)=f(a)*_2f(b)$ I can reach the conclusion, but I still have no clue.

Comment: Where specifically do you get stuck? Have you tried writing down exactly what both sides are and what your map does?

Comment: what does this $\mu_n$ signify?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $\mu_n$ is the set of $n^{th}$ roots of unity.

Since every $\alpha \in \mu_n$ is of form $e^{\frac{2\pi ki}{n}}$, which is just $f([k]_n)$, $f$ is a surjective function.

If $f([a_1]_n)=f([a_2]_n)$, then 
$$\exp{\frac{2\pi a_1i}{n}}=\exp{\frac{2\pi a_2i}{n}}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \exp {\frac{2\pi (a_1 -a_2)i}{n}}=1$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{2\pi (a_1 -a_2)i}{n}=2m\pi i$$
$$\Longrightarrow a_1-a_2=mn$$
$$\Longrightarrow a_1\equiv a_2 \mod m$$
Since $a_1,a_2\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, we get $a_1=a_2$. Thus $f$ is also injective due to which we get $f$ is bijective.

To show it is an isomorphism, we need to remember that the group operation in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is addition, whereas in $\mu_n$ it is multiplication. Remembering this we get
$$f([a+b]_n)=\exp{\frac{2\pi (a+b)i}{n}}=\exp{\frac{2\pi ai}{n}}\exp{\frac{2\pi bi}{n}}=f([a]_n)\times f([b]_n)$$

Which finishes the proof that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

A main point in such questions is to prove that the map $f$ is *well defined*, that is, it doesn't depend on the particular representative of the equivalence class $[a]_n$.

This can be avoided by using the homomorphism theorem.

Define $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}^*$ (the codomain is the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers) by
$$
\varphi(a)=\cos(2a\pi/n)+i\sin(2a\pi/n)
$$
It follows from well known properties of complex numbers that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism:
$$
\varphi(a+b)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)
$$
(it's essentially the addition formula for the sine and the cosine).

In particular, for every $a$,
$$
(\varphi(a))^n=\varphi(na)=\cos(2a\pi)+i\sin(2a\pi)=1
$$
so the image of $\varphi$ is contained in the subgroup $\mu_n$ consisting of the complex $n$-th roots of unity.

Moreover, you should be able to prove that $\ker\varphi=n\mathbb{Z}$.

With this at hand, the homomorphism $\varphi$ induces a unique homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mu_n$ such that, for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
f([a]_n)=\varphi(a)=\cos(2a\pi/n)+i\sin(2a\pi/n)
$$
The homomorphism $f$ is injective (homomorphism theorem) and so it is also surjective because its domain and codomain have the same number of elements.